# Is there a condition to determine if the Notion application is open?

Tags: notion-api

Given that the Notion API just came out, is there now a possibility of checking whether the Notion program itself is open or not as a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation [here](https://developers.notion.com/).

Nothing in there seems to cover this specific use-case at the moment.

Depending on if your app is a web app, a mobile app, or a native mac/windows/linux app. There might be other APIs to know if an app is installed.